# Treeview based on single field

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a single table which 1.000 rows and 6 columns. It has an ID field as index and a second field "Name" which contains the name of a specific object in thistable. As you can guess, Name is unique.

Names are something like "Plant.Tree.Apple.Pit" or "Animal_Mammal_Dog" or any other non-letter /non-digit as separator. Not a big problem. But I need to split these names into words and groep them by these words. Thus, my first example would be 4 levels and my second three levels deep. And then it needs to be displayed to the user within the browser.

What is the most efficient way to build this tree?

Comment: Are you open to database schema change suggestions or is it something that you cannot modify and absolutely need to do this `Plant.Tree.Apple.Pit` thing in your database?

Comment: Nope, the DB schema is fixed. Too many code already depends on this structure, else it would have been a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 'most efficient' usually depends on how you plan on accessing the data. Do you just need to parse the tree and then display it to the user, and thats it?

In that case, I suppose I would model it as a simple tree, made out of, say, Node objects.

There are other tree structures you could use, but they get more complicated, and again, that depends on how you intend on using this data. Are you building this tree on the webserver, and thus need to be as fast as possible to avoid cpu-starving it? Do you just display it to the user?

Another option would be to dump the raw rows to the page, then write javascript to generate the display tree from the dumped data. That way, your client's webbrowser does all the work of parsing the tree and displaying it.

**Edit to answer your comment**:

Alright, then would a standard tree structure work? I'd assume you know how to make one, but just in case:

You grab a row, parse its tokens. Starting with the first token and starting at the root of the tree, figure out if the token is a child of the current node; if so, set it as your current node, and move on to the next token. If not, insert it into the tree and make it your new current node. Mark these nodes as being namespace nodes. Repeat until you hit the last token, which is representing your ultimate object. Insert into the current node your object with its parameters.

You could do all of this with one class; have the class store the node type (namespace or object), a list of children nodes, and the the properties for the object when the node is of type object. Or you could do it with inheritance and casting, so that every node doesn't have to have parameters for the object, audible would be null in all of the namespace nodes.

Comment: Yep, parse the tree, show it to the user. Except that the leaves of the tree will show some of the additional fields. However, the problem is mainly building that node tree.